ValueListenableBuilder not triggering when setting the same value in Flutter
In the following Flutter code, a ValueListenableBuilder is used to show a dialog when a ValueNotifier changes. However, when the same value is set again, the dialog is not triggered.
ValueNotifier is only notifying listeners when the value changes. The goal is to trigger the dialog even if the same value (true) is set multiple times.
How can the dialog be triggered even if the same value (true) is set again to adWatchNeeded?
Lets assume a simple view model class like below, OR simple try it on here
Important: No state management solutions needed like bloc, riverpod etc. This is just for experimental purpose
class FeatureViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  ValueNotifier<bool> adWatchNeeded = ValueNotifier(false);

  void useFeature() {
    // Some API calls..
    // Unfortunately user must watch ads to use feature..
    adWatchNeeded.value = true;
  }
}

Then use on UI side
  Widget _buildAdWatchNeededDialog() {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
      valueListenable: _viewModel.adWatchNeeded,
      builder: (context, adWatchNeeded, child) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          if (adWatchNeeded) {
            showAdWatchNeededDiaog(context);
          }
        });
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
      },
    );
  }

Then use it on tree
class SomeFeatureWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SomeFeatureWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SomeFeatureWidget> createState() => _SomeFeatureWidgetState();
}

class _SomeFeatureWidgetState extends State<SomeFeatureWidget> {
  final _viewModel = FeatureViewModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _buildFeatureUsageDialog(),
        _buildAdWatchNeededDialog(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFeatureUsageDialog() {
    return TextButton(onPressed: () => _viewModel.useFeature(), child: const Text('Use Feature'));
  }

  Widget _buildAdWatchNeededDialog() {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
      valueListenable: _viewModel.adWatchNeeded,
      builder: (context, adWatchNeeded, child) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          if (adWatchNeeded) {
            showAdWatchNeededDiaog(context);
          }
        });
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
      },
    );
  }

  void showAdWatchNeededDiaog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: const Text('Wath ads to use this feature'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: const Text('Watch Ad')),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: const Text('No, thanks'))
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


write your custom version of ValueNotifier: just copy the original ValueNotifier sources and remove that if

very simple and super-duper solution :-)

btw why didn't you drop it as answer here ? It would also make sense @pskink

ok, posted an answer, check it out

@pskink implemented recently and seems working good, thanks

the easiest way is to write your own version of ValueNotifier
just copy the original sources of ValueNotifier from here (it's ~25 lines of code) and simply remove the if that checks if a new value is different that the old one in set value(T newValue) setter
it should look, more or less, something like this:
class MySuperDuperValueNotifier<T> extends ChangeNotifier implements ValueListenable<T> {
  MySuperDuperValueNotifier(this._value) {
    if (kFlutterMemoryAllocationsEnabled) {
      ChangeNotifier.maybeDispatchObjectCreation(this);
    }
  }

  @override
  T get value => _value;
  T _value;
  set value(T newValue) {
    _value = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '${describeIdentity(this)}($value)';
}



ValueNotifier is only notifying listeners when the value changes. The goal is to trigger the dialog even if the same value (true) is set multiple times.

This is how it is supposed to work, by definition.  If you need events even when the value is identical, consider using the events of a Stream, or including a microsecond timestamp in your value.
